# How to download AES ENCRYPTION .m3u8 video?

Tags: video, encryption, aes, m3u8

I'm trying to download a video from vzaar, but unable to download it.

Video: https://view.vzaar.com/16861921/player

Password: 569972

I tried using Livestreamer & ffmpeg.. but they're not working for me. I'm getting an error : ***'Failed to create decryptor'***.

So how do i download this video? Please help!

Comment: can anyone please help?!

Answer (score 0):

As Nevermore says the m3u8 file is just an index and I am not aware of any tools which will follow the links in the file and concatenate all the downloaded video segments into a single video file.

You could write a script to do this yourself but you would need to be aware that there might be multiple bit rates so you probably want to only download segments with a given bitrate.

Your question mentions encryption also - if the video is encrypted then you will not be able to view it even after all the above effort, unless you have the correct decryption key.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry to break it to you, but you can't download an m3u8 file, because that is actually a playlist file listing `HLS` *streaming*. This format is for streaming (and as such you cannot "download" it)